# Android Javascript Interface stops working after Resume

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I have a **WebView** that shows the content from a HTML file with a SVG object and inside it some clickable objects with a *onclick()* function calling the Android interface with *java.performClick()*.

Here's a code sample:

```
WebView wvMapa = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvMapa);
wvMapa.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wvMapa.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
wvMapa.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());    

WebSettings wsMapa = wvMapa.getSettings();
wsMapa.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wvMapa.addJavascriptInterface(new Object(){
    public void performClick(String id){
       /*MY ACTION*/
       }
    }, "java");
```

It works great on the first  run, but when I click Home button and after Resume  or open another Intent and go back, it doesn't work anymore. Looks like the JavascriptInterface is unattached everytime I leave the screen.

What's missing?

Comment: Is ALL javascript not working or just the interface? Are you pausing timers and not resuming timers on resume? You need to post more code. What you have there WILL work without issue.

Comment: It's a simple Activity and a simple Javascript code, there is no timers.